# How is a trace of commands different from shell input lines?

Tags: shell

I am unclear about two options when invoking a bash shell process or for `set`:

> -v Print shell input lines as they are read.
>
> -x Print a trace of simple commands, for commands, case commands, select commands, and arithmetic for commands and their argu- ments or
>   associated word lists after they are expanded and before they are
>   executed. The value of the PS4 variable is expanded and the resultant
>   value is printed before the command and its expanded arguments

How is a trace of commands different from shell input lines?

Answer (score 2):

The *trace* shows the lines which are *executed*, counting variable-substitution.  A verbose trace shows the lines which are *read*.

For comparison, `csh` has a verbose setting, which shows only lines read.  It is not as useful for debugging scripting problems.

By the way, both `-v` and `-x` are described in the POSIX [shell command language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set).  So this question is not bash-specific.